# Spring postgresql cannot connect to local database

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to test my Spring DAO level but cannot connect to my local database. Here is the Configuration.

Yes, I use port 54321 instead of standard port 5432:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:53421/mydbtest");
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean 
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate();
    template.setDataSource(dataSource());

    return template;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource)
{
    DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();    
    dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);        
    dataSourceInitializer.setEnabled(true);
     ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("src/resource/sql/01_init_database.sql"));
    dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);
    return dataSourceInitializer;
}
```

I switched the firewall off, tried different versions of postgresql driver. But I stilll get this exception. And he also writes me to check my user-password-port data, but I'm sure they are correct:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
```

What could be also wrong?

I use postgresql 9.2

**UPDATE**

I am on Windows if it matters

Here is the line for pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all                 0.0.0.0/0           trust
```

(I also tried md5)

Here a Snippet form postgres.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                # comma-separated list of addresses;
                # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                # (change requires restart)
port = 54321                # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
```

Comment: Is Postgres really running? Can you connect using `psql` or another SQL client? Does `localhost` actually resolve to an IP address? (does `ping localhost` work?) What is the value of `listen_address` in `postgresql.conf`

Comment: localhost is pinged. the value in postgresconf is listen_addresses = '*'

Answer (score 2):

Try to connect to PostgreSQL server on localhost:

```
psql -h localhost -p 53421
```

Are you able to connect? If not, what is an error?

---

Edit your PostgreSQL configuration:

**pg_hba.conf**

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

**postgresql.conf**

```
    listen_addresses='*'
port = 53421
```

and **restart** server.

(it's not connected to Spring, it's rather PostgreSQL configuration issue)

Comment: you are right: I cannot connect to locanhost from postgres. but pgAdmin cannot connect

Comment: What's the error message? "psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused" ?

Comment: I added this line and as far as i understand a restarted the server (with a command pg_clt start -D data). But I receive a message from restarting the cannot fins a configuration file and from psql still connection refused

Comment: Switch `-D` means data directory, you have to place there a system path to PostgreSQL data directory (and probably "data" is not correct directory, is it?).

Comment: It was a right directora. It finds now a file, but still cannot connect. I added an edit to the main post to show my conf files

Comment: A have you restarted the server and server properly boot-up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134897/discussion-between-user1315357-and-user2957954).